# Ng-token-auth not compatible with Angular 1.6.1?

Tags: angularjs

Alright, so I injected Ng-token-auth to my app and now an error shows up into my console:

'$http.get(...).success is not a function.

Doing some reading, Angular deprecated .success method after 1.6 version.

What can I do to make it work? Unfourtanetly I'm using Angular-Material which use 1.6 and cannot go back to a previuos version. What should I do?

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/ng-token-auth/issues/347

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http , `$http.get('/someUrl', config).then(successCallback, errorCallback);`

Comment: @Jordan.J.D They know about it (`Doing some reading, Angular deprecated .success method after 1.6 version.`). They're asking about a module that use the old `success` function

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research this was fix on they last commit but is not available in Bower yet. So I had to download myself from [their official git site](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/ng-token-auth)